# Were women present in the Temple when offering the Korban Pesach?

Tags: women, korban, tznius-modesty, mechitza-partition, korban-pesach

Women are obligated to bring a korban Pesach. The mishna even talks about a group of women doing their own.

So does that mean in the afternoon of the 14th of Nissan, you'd find both men and women in the Temple courtyard? Or were women expected to stay in the ladies' section, and find some man who would bring their lamb in on their behalf?

Comment: Kiddushin 52b But why is this different form any other day when women might be bringing offerings for whatever reason?

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you! Basically a massive machlokes Rashi and Tosfos on all these instances if she entered, or always had to have a man do it for her; no? Was just thinking about the logistics with a huge crowd. Would seem tricky to have hundreds of women waiting outside, hoping that all the men they sent kept all the lambs straight.

Comment: I think more likely the reality was that an all-female korban pesach was extremely rare so there would virtually always be a male available to bring it.

Comment: IRRC, the Mishna in Succah says that only at the end of the Second Temple a decree on the separation between men and women on festival celebrations was issued and wooden ramps for women were built. Prior to that, no separation was practiced.